# Ola Hallengren's SQL Server Maintenance Solution & CMD Syntax

Tags: ola-hallengren

I'm using the free version of SQL Server Management Studio so I have to use CMD to call the SQL scripts.  The official page gives an example of the CMD syntax used to call the "DatabaseBackup" script, as follows:

> Create cmd files to execute the stored procedures; for example: sqlcmd
> -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d master -Q "EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @Directory = N'C:\Backup', @BackupType = 'FULL'" -b -o C:\Log\DatabaseBackup.txt

I got that to work, but I can't get it to work for the "DatabaseIntegrityCheck" or the "IndexOptimize" scripts.

I guess I don't know the syntax.  I tried using the example code and just replacing the script name, but that didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

[How to automate SQL Server Express database maintenance using Windows Task Scheduler and Ola Hallengren’s maintenance solution](https://www.haurumit.dk/how-to-automate-sql-server-express-database-maintenance-using-windows-task-scheduler-and-ola-hallengrens-maintenance-solution/) has numerous examples of using `SQLCMD` to run Ola's scripts.

For example:

**Database integrity check**

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d Tools -Q "EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseIntegrityCheck @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @LogToTable = 'Y';" -b -o D:\OLA\Logs\DatabaseIntegrityCheckUserDatabases.txt
```

**Index optimize**

```
sqlcmd -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d Tools -Q "EXECUTE dbo.IndexOptimize @Databases = 'USER_DATABASES', @LogToTable = 'Y';" -b -o D:\OLA\Logs\IndexOptimizeUserDatabases.txt
```